# ansible 401 error in uri module but shell curl work

Tags: ansible

I have tried uri module in ansible, but I have still 401 authentication errors.
In shell module when I am using curl all works.
Can somebody please try to translate to uri code ?

```
- name: Get authentication token
  uri:
    url: https://myIPcontrol.com:8443/inc-rest/api/v1/login
    method: POST
    timeout: 30
    validate_certs: no
    headers:
        Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        Accept: application/json
    body:
      username: admin
      password: mypsw
    body_format: json
    return_content: yes
  register: authtoken
  
  
- name: Get authentication token
  shell: "curl -k  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: 
      application/json' -d 'username=admin&password=mypsw' -X POST  
      https://myIPcontrol.com:8443/inc-rest/api/v1/login"
  register: authtoken
```

Comment: A 401 comes from the server. Investigate what's different from the server's perspective if you want a sure answer -- is it looking at the `User-Agent`, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executing via the shell, your body (`-d`) is passed as `username=admin&password=mypsw`. This structure is `form-urlencoded` but you are passing `body_format: json` so Ansible is passing the body as `{"user":"admin","password":"mypsw"}` in conflict with the `Content-Type` header you set.

Instead use

```
body:
  username: admin
  password: mypsw
body_format: form-urlencoded
```

The rest looks correct to me.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html